# How can I stop for sending the promise until a for-each loop generate an array which will be send as promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous function `investedList` which queried from the database and do some changes in result from database. Database result name - `campaignList` which is an array of javascript object .

I want to traverse array and do some changes in this object wise. I am able to traverse and change the object `campaignList`, but I am unable to send the whole array as promise some how at the process of loop -  `defered.resolve()` works in between it.

So how can I make thing works as i want?

```
  var invest = require('../models/investment');
  var Q = require('q');
  var CampaignDao = require('./campaignDao');
  var _ = require('underscore');

  module.exports.investedList = function(data){
   var defered = Q.defer();
   var projection ={
        _id : false,
       campaignId : true,
       amountInvested : true,
       tokensRecieved : true,
        campaignName : true
}
invest.find({investorId:data.userId},projection,function(err,campaignList){
    if(err){
        defered.reject(err);
    }else{
         var arr =[];
        _.each(campaignList,function(obj){
           delete obj._id; 
        });
        _.each(campaignList , function(obj){

        id=obj.campaignId;
 var temp={ 
campaignId: obj.campaignId,
campaignName: obj.campaignName,
amountInvested: obj.amountInvested,
tokensRecieved: obj.tokensRecieved
};
            CampaignDao.commonInfo(id)
            .then(function(data){
                temp.country = data.project.projectCountry;
                temp.domain = data.project.domain;
                temp.city = data.project.city;
                temp.amountRaised = data.campaign.amountRaised;
                arr.push(temp);
            }).catch(function(err){
                defered.reject(err);
            });
      });
      defered.resolve(arr);    
    } 
});
return defered.promise;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is currently quite hard to apprehend your code. Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of this code?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently calling deferred resolve parallel to _.each.

So resolve gets called before _.each is even finished.

Instead call resolve inside _.each either based on some condition. Condition can be to check whether you have changed the object campaignList completely.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check if your arr length is now equal campaignList length which is your loop array then if it is do the resolve()

```
var invest = require('../models/investment');
var Q = require('q');
var CampaignDao = require('./campaignDao');
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports.investedList = function(data){
var defered = Q.defer();
var projection ={
    _id : false,
   campaignId : true,
   amountInvested : true,
   tokensRecieved : true,
    campaignName : true
}
invest.find({investorId:data.userId},projection,function(err,campaignList){
    if(err){
        defered.reject(err);
    }else{
         var arr =[];
        _.each(campaignList,function(obj){
           delete obj._id; 
        });
        _.each(campaignList , function(obj){

            id=obj.campaignId;
             var temp={ 
                campaignId: obj.campaignId,
                campaignName: obj.campaignName,
                amountInvested: obj.amountInvested,
                tokensRecieved: obj.tokensRecieved
            };
            CampaignDao.commonInfo(id)
                .then(function(data){
                    temp.country = data.project.projectCountry;
                    temp.domain = data.project.domain;\\
                    temp.city = data.project.city;
                    temp.amountRaised = data.campaign.amountRaised;
                    // insert object into array
                    arr.push(temp);
                    if (arr.length >= campaignList.length) {
                        // if array is full resolve the promise
                        defered.resolve(arr);    
                    }
                }).catch(function(err){
                    defered.reject(err);
                });
            });
        } 
    });
    return defered.promise;
}
```